# Stuck in login loop with an error report

Tags: 16.04, login, lightdm

Ok, so I have tried everything I've seen but every time i try to log in (no matter what account) it says "System program problem detected" then the screen goes black and right back to the login screen. (I currently have Ubuntu 16.04)

So far i have tried the `.Xauthority` `ls -lah` stuff but that has done nothing

I tried the `ls -ld/tmp` and i get `drwxrwxrwt 10 root root 4096 Nov  5 21:52 /tmp`

I then made a new account and gave that admin and tried to login but I got the same error

Then I tried the purge, reinstall, and then reconfigure lightdm but when I tried to reconfigure it game me this error `/user/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure must be run as a root`

I don't know what to do now besides completely reinstalling ubuntu, which I'd like to avoid. Please help.

Comment: `/user/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure`? Surely you mean `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure`. Did you try to run it as root, i. e. with `sudo`? What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`? See [How do I save terminal output to a file?](/q/420981/175814) and [How do I get information from the logs on my computer when I only have access to the command line?](/q/440087/175814) if you don't know how to capture the output and insert it into your question from a virtual terminal.

Answer (score 0):

IF you can't log into the GUI log into the console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and entering your user ID and password at the prompts.

Then remove the crash report files with:

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

Then use:

```
sudo reboot
```

Then try to login with the GUI again.