# System error while entering my password

Tags: system

I just restarted my Ubuntu pc and now whenever I am entering my password for signing in or shows 'System program problem detected' and after that it asks me again to enter password.

Comment: You might find some helpful info here: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/q/223501/301745)

Comment: Related: [Stuck in login loop with an error report](https://askubuntu.com/q/846083/301745)

Comment: Possibly related? [Getting “System program problem detected” pops up regularly after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/q/133385/301745)

Comment: @wjandrea thanks.. I just uninstall amd drivers that I have installed last time and now I m able to login